# Why does my program work fine by running it directly but not as a service? Linux C

Tags: c, makefile, service, raspberry-pi, sdk

Goodday guys,

I am trying to build and run program in linux (raspberry) as a service.
It is a sample application that uses the Cerence SDK C API that implements a wake-up-word (WUW) plus command utterance recognition.

I can execute it by ./name.exe or using the Makefile commands.

The problem is that when I execute the program by console it works fine, without any problem.
When I try to execute it as a service (using both systemd or crontab and also rc.local), an error occours.

**This is the function that gives me error:**

```
printf("Selecting audio configuration %s\n", audioScenarioName);
rc = nuance_audio_IAudioManager_activateScenario(audioMgr, audioScenarioName);
if (NUANCE_COMMON_OK != rc) {
    printf("Audio scenario activation failed: %d\n", rc); <-- returns 1 (error, impossible to activate scenario)
    return rc;
}
```

ActivateScenario it's a function that simply selects the correct mic (audioScenarioName) following a JSON file and the audio manager (audioMgr).
Unfortunately this function returns 1 if something goes wrong, closes the program and nothing else.

**This is the JSON:**

```
"type":                "AudioInput",
    "name":                "mic_input",
    "adapter_type":        "CUSTOM_AUDIO",
    "adapter_params": {
        "device_name": "default"
    },
    "audio_format":      { "uses": "16khz_1ch" }
```

The service should be running as root permissions (default).
I also tried by setting the whole folder as `chmod -R 777` as a test, but same problem.

**This is my service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=+/home/pi/.../nameexec
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
KillMode=process                        
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've also set the absolute path of its lib directory that it needs into the ld.so.conf file.
The only libraries I put in it are the .so ones, but not .h.

I am now trying to understand what might be different about starting the same executable but in different ways.

Could it be a permissions issue? Or is it not detecting the microphone? Any library out of place?

I really don't know why it works with the classic command and not as a service.
Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's hard to help without some clue as to what `nuance_audio_IAudioManager_activateScenario` is doing.

Comment: I usually have permission, path error or "bad" environnement variable problem when i'm doing this kind of action (executing the code in command line vs as a service). A good start would be to know if `nuance_audio_IAudioManager_activateScenario` return a code error (not just a boolean) and if yes, what this code error mean. After that, you can check permission, env var, path ....

Comment: Thanks for the replies!!! I just edited the post trying to respond to your comments.

Comment: Thank you again, but I think I succeeded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded!
The problem was the microphone being used.
Using Raspbian ver. Desktop, I set the mic from the bottom right part of the taskbar and changed the defaults in/out.
But these settings seem to be not system-wide and not used by the services in background (even though the "User=" is set to "pi").

So I had to change alsa.conf file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

Then find and edit these lines:

```
defaults.ctl.card cardnumber
defaults.pcm.card cardnumber
```

You can find the **card number** by running `arecord -l`.